# SharePoint Lists and Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel, excel-import

I have a SharePoint List of Training Competencies that I am importing into Excel. My intention is for the List to act as the master for all the competencies and an Excel sheet for each trainee. When I add a competency to the list it'll cascade down to each person's Excel sheet.

In the Excel sheet, I'm adding two columns to table created by the SP List import: status and date completed. When I add a new competency, the data in my added columns is static while the competency is dynamic.

Is it possible to tie the data in the status/date columns to a unique competency?

Comment: Alternatively, a SP list for each trainee is probably a better implementation. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality but SP List to SP List?